# Free market vs high income

Tags: free-market

While [answering](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/32115/21304) this question I was doing some research and [**found that**](https://www.heritage.org/index/heatmap)

[image]

the [high-income world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Bank_high-income_economy) has Free Markets.

Is it that because they are high-income, they have free markets, Or, is it that their free market made them high-income?

A supplementary question is: if the latter is true, why don't all low-income countries adopt Free Markets?

Comment: You ask two interesting and important questions.  Both however are very broad and could encourage opinion-based answers.  I'm voting to close the question as it stands as not really suitable for this site (see guidance [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  If closed, the question can be reopened if you edit it to make it more specific (eg perhaps "What evidence is there for or against the hypothesis that free markets tend to result in high incomes?)

Comment: It would be interesting to know, whether the income shown in the map is the gross or net income per person.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is it that because they are high-income, they have free markets, Or,
>   is it that their free market made them high-income?

Free market leads to or significantly contributes to a nation's high income.

> why don't all low-income countries adopt Free Markets?

Free markets are not a sufficient condition for prosperity. Many low-income countries with a supposedly market-economy remain undeveloped because rampant corruption in those countries outpaces or absorbs the benefits that free markets bring to the economy.

Elsewhere, ignorance and political interests are the main impediments to the adoption of a market economy. The notion of so-called *welfare state* is utilized to dissimulate or justify the mechanism or structures with which certain types of reactionary groups retain power.

In socialist (or de-facto socialist) countries, sectors like labor unions retain much of their influence notwithstanding the gaps in their leaders' economics background. A market economy typically results in a loss of concessions those groups are not willing to give up.

Comment: This answer has no scientific references, it is purely opinion based. Even if I agree with the conclusion, the answer is of poor quality.

Comment: The last part starting with "The notion of so-called welfare state ..." is plain wrong. For example the scandinavian countries have a market based economy and are well known for a healthy welfare situation. The role of labor unions is maybe in some situations ambivalent, but it should never contradict high income for the society. Fighting for high income is a prior goal for trade unions.

Comment: @giftnuss (1) I wouldn't consider "*market based economy*" one where people are [taxed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_tax_rates) 55% (Denmark) or 60% (Sweden) of their income. Where's *market freedom* if a government confiscates that much of consumers' income? (2) A scheme that relies on the demographic pyramids the West stopped experiencing in the late XX century is not a  *healthy* welfare situation, especially where coupled with automation-fueled unemployment. (3) Unions fighting for high income doesn't mean their demands are informed, affordable, or even functional.

Comment: @IñakiViggers (1) Public security, health system, affordable education, public traffic  are goods provided by the state. In a working democracy the high tax rate can become an investment in this goods and is by far not an contradiction to a free market. (2) This topic is to complex to be discussed via comment. For example it exists automation-fueled driver for higher incomes. So the unemployment is only one side of the coin. (3) Trade unions don't have an interest to ruin profitable business. If an capitalist can't make a deal with the trade union it is maybe his business which is wrong.

Comment: @gitnuss (1) The fact that some of the taxes are given back in the form of services still infringes market freedom by depriving economic agents of their ability to manage their resources in accordance with their own priorities. (2) Taxing automation-fueled income more aggressively is not going to cover the increasing deficits of welfare institutions, but yes, the topic is too complex to be addressed via comments. (3) I didn't say unions aim at ruining profitable business, but that their demands are out of touch with reality and oftentimes not even functional.

Comment: "Where's market freedom if a government confiscates that much of consumers' income?" Please put this into your bio, it will be helpful for people who wonder where you get your economics knowledge from.

Comment: @denesp Where exactly is your confusion? If "*confiscate*" sounds too harsh, bear in mind the extent of scrutiny on people's revenues; (2) entities' pursuit of a fiscal paradise; and (3) the sanctions for not paying taxes "voluntarily". There is certainly a need for *reasonable* taxation in order to run a government, but it is undeniable that --say-- income tax rate represents the portion of each year a person works only to fund the government's functions/agenda/experiments. If welfare state matches an individual's personal priorities, then good for him; but not all of us have that preference.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalism works best when there is elasticity- the price can go up or down by a marginal unit without running into the problem of plateauing supply or demand.

In extremely wealthy or extremely poor places, the market can experience inelasticity- where a change in the price will not affect demand.

**Cheap item inelasticity:**
E.g. The water is free at restaurants but we don't see people drinking insane quantities of water, though supply/$0 should equal infinite demand.

**Expensive item inelasticity:**
Someone is stranded in the desert and has no water. A vending machine offers him water for 100 gold coins. Even though the price is very high, the man still needs water. To save his life, the man would pay 100 or even 200 coins, doubling the price without reducing the demand. As it happens, the man has only one coin and dies because the vending machine was unable to adjust its price to make a sale.

Cheap item inelasticity is rarely a problem because if a country is stuck with undesirable surplus, it could just burn it or throw it in the sea.

Expensive item inelasticity is more prevalent in poorer places where more of the population is unable to afford important goods. A country could A) allow its people to starve B) subsidize goods for the poor C) set a maximum price for the item.

B and C are not free-market options.

A poorer economy is more likely to run into the problem of Expensive Item Inelasticity and is thus more likely to attempt to resolve it.

Comment: Re *"...burn it or throw it into the sea..."*:  This neglects the considerable national (and world) costs of environmental air and water pollution.